# Define a new method with only a few changes

Tags: julia

I want to write a version that accepts a supplementary argument. The difference with the initial version only resides in a few lines of codes, potentially within loops. A typical example is to user a vector of weight `w`.

One solution is to completely rewrite a new function

```
function f(Vector::a)
   ...
   for x in a
      ...
      s += x[i]
      ... 
   end
   ...
end

function f(a::Vector, w::Vector)
   ... 
   for x in a
     ...
     s += x[i] * w[i]
     ...
   end
   ...
end
```

This solution duplicates code and therefore makes the program harder to maintain.
I could split `...` into different helper functions, which are called by both functions, but the resulting code would be hard to follow

Another solution is to write only one function and use a `? :` structure for each line that should be changed

```
function f(a, w::Union(Nothing, Vector) = nothing)
   ....
   for x in a
      ...
      s += (w == nothing)? x[i] : x[i] * w[i]
      ...
   end
   ....
end
```

This code requires to check a condition at every step in a loop, which does not sound efficient, compared to the first version.

I'm sure there is a better solution, maybe using macros. What would be a good way to deal with this?

Comment: You could do the check before the loop starts, and set the result to a boolean variable.

Comment: Thanks. but suppose `x[i]` is an int and `x[i] w[i]` is a float. Would not that introduce type instability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing, ranging from optional arguments to custom types to metaprogramming with `@eval`'ed code generation (this would splice in the changes for each new method as you loop over a list of possibilities).

I think in this case I'd use a combination of the approaches suggested by @ColinTBowers and @GnimucKey.

It's fairly simple to define a custom array type that is all `ones`:

```
immutable Ones{N} <: AbstractArray{Int,N}
    dims::NTuple{N, Int}
end
Base.size(O::Ones) = O.dims
Base.getindex(O::Ones, I::Int...) = (checkbounds(O, I...); 1)
```

I've chosen to use an `Int` as the element type since it tends to promote well.  Now all you need is to be a bit more flexible in your argument list and you're good to go:

```
function f(a::Vector, w::AbstractVector=Ones(size(a))
    …
```

This should have a lower overhead than either of the other proposed solutions; `getindex` should inline nicely as a bounds check and the number `1`, there's no type instability, and you don't need to rewrite your algorithm.  If you're sure that all your accesses are in-bounds, you could even remove the bounds checking as an additional optimization.  Or on a recent 0.4, you could define and use `Base.unsafe_getindex(O::Ones, I::Int...) = 1` (that won't quite work on 0.3 since it's not guaranteed to be defined for all AbstractArrays).

Comment: Actually, in looking at the LLVM IR, I'm pretty sure that the multiplication is constant-folded away.  So the only overhead here is `checkbounds` — and that can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, using [Optional Arguments](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/functions/#optional-arguments) may play the trick.

Just make the `w` argument default to `ones()`.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up against this problem a few times. If you want to avoid the conditional if statement inside the loop, one possibility is to use multiple dispatch over some dummy types. For example:

```
abstract MyFuncTypes

type FuncWithNoWeight <: MyFuncTypes; end
evaluate(x::Vector, i::Int, ::FuncWithNoWeight) = x[i]

type FuncWithWeight{T} <: MyFuncTypes
    w::Vector{T}
end
evaluate(x::Vector, i::Int, wT::FuncWithWeight) = x[i] * wT.w[i]


function f(a, w::MyFuncTypes=FuncWithNoWeight())
    ....
    for x in a
        ...
        s += evaluate(x, i, w)
        ...
    end
    ....
end
```

I extend the `evaluate` method over `FuncWithNoWeight` and `FuncWithWeight` in order to get the appropriate behaviour. I also nest these types within an abstract type `MyFuncTypes`, which is the second input to `f` (with default value of `FuncWithNoWeight`). From here, multiple dispatch and Julia's type system takes care of the rest.

One neat thing about this approach is that if you decide later on you want to add a third type of behaviour inside the loop (not necessarily even weighting, pretty much any type of transformation will be possible), it is as simple as defining a new type, nesting it under `MyFuncTypes`, and extending the `evaluate` method to the new type.

**UPDATE:** As Matt B. has pointed out, the first version of my answer accidentally introduced type instability into the function with my solution. As a general rule I typically find that if Matt posts something it is worth paying close attention (hint, hint, check out his answer). I'm still learning a lot about Julia (and am answering questions on StackOverflow to facilitate that learning). I've updated my answer to remove the type instability pointed out by Matt.

Comment: dummyType is still type-unstable in the above code. While I don't think it will result in many allocations, it will prevent evaluate from inlining directly into the for loop, and I think Julia look up the dispatch every time it's called (even though we know it's not changing). It's better to move the selection of the different types into the default argument, so the type is always the same within the function body.

Comment: @MattB. Ah, thanks for that. I had not noticed that that pattern of code would introduce type instability, but I can see it now. I've updated my answer. Now to go and update the places in my own code where I've made this mistake :-)

Comment: There is an issue with the code. You need to parametrize FuncWithWeight with the eltype of w. Otherwise the function f is not specialized to the eltype of `w` (I tried to edit your answer but was not accepted).

Comment: @Matthew Agreed. Updated.